# Passing string command line argument to bash script for a particular linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have found the following command online to search texts in pdf's

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "your pattern"' \;
```

I want to automate this, by doing through script, so i wrote this in a script file search_pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$1"' \;
```

There is some mistake in this script, it is not working as expected. Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try exporting the `$1` in your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern=$1
export pattern

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$pattern"' \;
```

But I suggest to rewrite it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pattern=$1
export pattern

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'for f; do
  pdftotext "$f" - | grep --with-filename  --color "$pattern"
done' _ {} +
```

Maybe add the `--label=$pattern` also

Comment: what is the difference between first and second one

Comment: The second is more readable for me at least. but you can use whatever you like.

Comment: The second one only launches one shell process (to handle a bunch of files) rather than a separate shell for each file, so it'll be more efficient (though not by a great deal, since it still has to run `pdftotext` and `grep` separately for each file). Also, it avoids some possible parsing problems with certain weird filename characters.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I also remember about shell injection issues when doing something like "{}" in find but I'm not sure though, I just don't touch the `{}` in find.

Comment: @md.jamal, the `\;` process each files for every `-exec` call while  `+` tries process as much files as possible while avoiding `ARGMAX` see http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: @Jetchisel Yeah, if you have a filename that contains `$(somecommand)` or its backtick equivalent, any version with `"{}"` embedded in the shell command (as opposed to being an argument to it, like your second version), will go ahead and execute that command. (And then probably fail to do the right thing to that file.) Some other characters & sequences will cause ... other problems.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind, just in case, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass parameter `$0` as name of the shell for error messages and positional parameter `$1` to the `sh -c '...'` call:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$1"
' sh "$1" \;
```

Here, `sh` is used as `$0` (can be any name) and the original argument `"$1"` is passed as positional parameter `$1`.

If you have `pdfgrep` installed, you wouldn't need the pdf to text conversion and the extra shell:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep -H "$1" {} \;
```